# What is differences between signals for QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, python, qt, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I have 3 `connect function` in `pyQt` and are related to `3 signal`,`one slot` and `one widget`:

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("itemClicked(QTableWidgetItem*)")),
                           lambda:  self.materialsInstance.setFilterDict_Insert("TW",self,"imported_party_attributes",0,self.tableWidget.currentItem().row(),self.tableWidget.currentItem().column()))
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("cellChanged(int,int)")),
                           lambda: self.materialsInstance.setFilterDict_Insert("TW",self,"imported_party_attributes",0,self.tableWidget.currentItem().row(),self.tableWidget.currentItem().column()))
    ###clear cell and remove from dict
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("currentCellChanged(int,int,int,int)")),
                           lambda: self.materialsInstance.setFilterDict_Insert("TW",self,"imported_party_attributes",0,self.tableWidget.currentItem().row(),self.tableWidget.currentItem().column()))#,"currentCellChanged(int,int,int,int))"))
```

I didn't any problem with 2 first `connect function`, But i get the following traceback for 3th `connect function`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/materialsInsertFrame.py", line 244, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.materialsInstance.setFilterDict_Insert("TW",self,"imported_party_attributes",0,self.tableWidget.currentItem().row(),self.tableWidget.currentItem().column()))#,"currentCellChanged(int,int,int,int))"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'row'
```

I didn't any idea on `Signal-Sloting`, Do you have ?

**NOTE:** 2 first `connect functions`  work fine.

**My question** is , What's differences between first 2 `signal` and last `signal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.tableWidget.currentItem()` can return None if there is no current item. You must always check if it is not None before using `row()` or `column()` on its result. This issue is not related to the nature of signals you use.

Answer (score 0):

I solved, Signals are related to QTableWidget are 2 sets:

1. related to current time
2. no related to time.

At first option, i user get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'row'` because user doesn't click on widget, but in second option,We don't need time and don't get the given `traceback`.